# C++ STL for accessing equally spaced non contiguous elements of a vector

Tags: std

I have defined a 1D vector for storing matrix values and want to extract all the elements which happen to lie in a column of a matrix. I know we can write a template but is there exists any STL for such task. Thanks

Comment: The first row start at index `0`, right? Then the second row should start on index `0 + row_width`, right? And the third row on index `0 + row_width + row_width`. And so on. It should be easy to figure out a pattern here, and how to get an arbitrary column. If you laid it out on paper it should have been pretty obvious IMO.

Comment: Thanks.Actually I want to find the max element  in the extracted sub vector and was thinking if some library similar to max_elements can be applied directly to non contiguous elements of 1D vector.

Comment: Well you could create an iterator-like class to handle it, that you can pass to standard algorithm functions. Most algorithm functions (including [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)) requires a [*forward iterator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) which is relatively straightforward to implement.